# Content overlapping onto responsive header

Tags: css

Working on https://faraz-manan-2apz.squarespace.com   have a quick scroll through and come back (view as visitor and enter captcha)

Header image is meant to be fullscreen on all devices, which it is. good.

but I want the squares with the pictures (id="page") to start at the end of the header image, regardless of the viewing device.

I tried adding padding in different % but the gap between header and content looks weird.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `#header`'s height to `100vh` so it will be the same as the viewport height. Then change `#page`'s `padding-top` to `calc(100vh + 50px)` to push it to 50px below the viewport height.